# Automorphism of linear algebraic group $G$ preserves finite dimensional subspace of $k[G]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm struggling to understand a claim in Springers "linear algebraic groups".

Suppose $G$ is a linear algebraic group and $\sigma$ an automorphism of $G$ as an algebraic group. How can I show the dual action of $\sigma$ on $k[G]$ stabilizes a finite dimensional subspace of generators?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it using the following general fact (also written in Springer's book somewhere) :

An algebraic representation $G \times V \to V$ is the same as a comodule map $a : V \to V \otimes k[G]$ (where $k[G]$ is the ring of regular functions on $G$).

Now, if $v \in V$, we have $a(v) = \sum v_i \otimes f_i$ where each $f_i$ is a polynomial in $k[G]$. It follows from the comodule axiom that the subspace generated by the $v_i$ is $G$-stable and finite-dimensional. So actually $V$ is the union of finite-dimensional $G$-stable modules.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i don't see how this gives me a subspace stable under the action of σ though. could you elaborate on that?